# sql select with distinct order marks 75

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my SQL command:

```
select name
from students
where marks > 75
order by right(name,3)
```

Output:

```
Vivek 
Belvet 
Devil 
Evil
```

I don't want to see last 3 char are same in words like de**vil** and e**vil**. I want to see only devil.

Comment: why devil but not evil? extra criteria?

Comment: I agree with Alex; you must define why you prefer 'devil' over 'evil'; what is the rule to apply?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to avoid two names ending with same last 3 characters:

```
select name
from students s1
where marks > 75
  and not exists (select 1 from students s2
                  where s2.marks > 75
                    and right(s2.name,3) = right(s1.name,3)
                    and s2.name < s1.name)
order by right(name,3)
```

Only the first name with same last 3 characters will be returned.

Comment: Looks like missing `AND` in where clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `MIN` or `MAX` as following:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [value] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([value])
VALUES ('Vivek')
      ,('Belvet')
      ,('Helvet')
      ,('Devil')
      ,('Petko')
      ,('Zetko')
      ,('Evil');

 SELECT MIN([value])
 FROM @DataSource
 GROUP BY RIGHT([value], 3);
```

`MIN` will give you the first name, ordering name in ascending way, and `MAX` is the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below,but you should specify why  `I want to see only devil.`,but not evil..Below code chooses one arbitrarily

```
;with cte
as
(
select *,
dense_rank() over (order by right(name,3) as rnk
from
table where marks>75
)
select * from cte where rnk=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name from students
where marks > 75 
order by right(name,3) asc , id asc;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).